# How to use ngClass to set the First class on an element?

Tags: angularjs, semantic-ui, ng-class

I'm well aware of many ways to use ngClass to add classes to elements. But the classes added by ngClass always appear to be appended at the end of the element's classes. Is there a straightforward way to set the first class on an element?

For instance, in a framework like [Semantic](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html#columns) these are different:

`<div class="nine wide column>`

and

`<div class="wide column nine">`

I want to use ngClass to set the first class, so that something like this would work:

`<div class="wide column" ng-class="vm.isWide() ? 'sixteen' : 'nine'">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS Rules are the best solution here.**

While it might not be as satisfying as finding an esoteric way to get `ngClass` to order the classes, it's the best solution here.

Essentially you mimic the framework's grid rules. With Semantic UI, which uses a 16-cell grid, adding these new CSS rules will enable you to use `ngClass` as above.

Add this to your style sheet:

```
 /* Fix for Semantic / Angular class ordering */
  .wide.column.sixteen
    width 100% !important
  .wide.column.nine
    width 56% !important
```

And then your `ngClass` that needs the classes ordered will work. You can write the html element using `ngClass` like this:

```
<div class="wide column" ng-class="vm.isWide() ? 'sixteen' : 'nine'">
```

This will work, based on the return value for `isWide()`

To use this type of `ngClass` throughout your app, if it uses semantic-ui's grid, add these classes to your CSS sheet:

```
  /* Fix for Semantic / Angular class ordering */
  .wide.column.sixteen
    width 100% !important
  .wide.column.fifteen
    width 94% !important
  .wide.column.fourteen
    width 88% !important
  .wide.column.thirteen
    width 82% !important
  .wide.column.twelve
    width 75% !important
  .wide.column.eleven
    width 69% !important
  .wide.column.ten
    width 63% !important
  .wide.column.nine
    width 56% !important
  .wide.column.eight
    width 50% !important
  .wide.column.seven
    width 44% !important
  .wide.column.six
    width 37% !important
  .wide.column.five
    width 31% !important
  .wide.column.four
    width 25% !important
  .wide.column.three
    width 18% !important
  .wide.column.two
    width 12% !important
  .wide.column.one
    width 6% !important
```

Compare with Semantic's grid definition [here](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html#/definition).

Answer (score 0):

I think the ngClass just add a modifier css class to element, so it should be added in the last of the class list.

In my idea, can you try this:

```
<div class="{{setClass()}} wide column nine"></div>

<script>
     $scope.setClass = function () {
     var class1 = "wrapper" 
     return class1 ;
     }
</script>
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea -- to try to trick it since it seems to push/pop from a list somewhere. But you solution doesn't remove the other class ('nine' in this case)

Comment: Are you try to move a class in the classes list to the first? Sorry for my English :)

Comment: No the idea is that class would be dynamic depending on a boolean function (`isWide()`) that will change.  I want the classes to go back and forth, depending on the function value, from `sixteen wide column` to `nine wide column`.

Comment: This might be a bug/shortcoming of AngularJS, that there is no way to affect the order that classes appear.